How can I deploy my Winform application for users?
Please help me.
If I create a Winform application, is there somewhere to deploy it for users use ?
Show me how, please !
I created an app using C# in visual studio. Now, I want people to use it. Shortly, I want people to use in another pc. How to do it ?

Use Wix: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/intro/

Is this in a corporate network? Do you want to sell it? Do you want to let just anyone download and run it? Have you done any work to ensure your users will already have .NET installed, or do you need to bundle an installer?

I'd strongly recommend re-reading @JoelCoehoorn's comment (and answering the questions he asks) and then doing an internet search for the useful words in something like "publish and deploy windows forms app" (you'll also want to look up "click once")

the simplest way
go to root of your project => bin => Debug => net8.0-windows (if available)
copy this folder and past it in another pc
when you double click on your ("NameProject.exe") you can run the program
if you do not know the root of your project you can right click on project name in solution explorer then select "open folder in file explore"

Thank you for your question. To answer your question, there are several options:

You can create click-once application from Visual Studio. Select
your project in Solution Explorer, right click on the project and
select Properties. Then, from the menu on the left side select    Publish. You will see all the options related to publishing your
application.
Basically, you will have to enter publish location (this is the place where your setup files will be created - and these are setup.exe and .application file). You can then distribute these files on CD, USB stick or any other media. You can also choose to put your installation on some server that is accessible for your users, so that they can download your application.
You can learn more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/deploying-applications-services-and-components?view=vs-2022.

Wix toolset

Standalone programs that will create installers (such as .exe or .msi). There are many such programs, and some of them are also free to use, e.g.:

ActualInstaller - this one has a nice UI, you can customize the look of your installer and also specify any prerequisites, such as required framework or minimal Windows version etc.

NSIS - this one is also free but is more complex and requires you to write a script. There are many examples of these scripts: https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Category:Code_Examples.



Sometimes (not recommended), simply creating a ZIP file from ALL the files you get in .bin/release folder may be sufficient, but options 1 or 2 are way better!


In cases 2,3 and 4 you will have to place your setup files on the server yourself, so that users can download setup files and install your app, or you can distribute setup file(s) on some media, like USB.
I hope this will help!
